# Calculating the Macaulay duration of a floating-rate bond

Tags: fixed-income, bond, duration

I am new to the pricing of bonds:

Suppose that I would like to price a floating-rate bond with par value \$100, with maturity at $T$ years from now, paying coupons semi-annually.

Suppose that $r_{n-0.5,n} $ denotes the annual interest rate from time $n-0.5$ to time $n$, where $n \in \Pi:=\{ 0.5, 1, \ldots, T-0.5, T\}.$ For each $n \in \Pi $, let the coupon rate $c_n$ be defined by
$$ c_n := \frac{r_{n-0.5,n}}{2}. $$ Let $r_0:= 7.5 \%$ and that the yield curve is flat at $7.5 \%$ as well.

Therefore, the cash-flow of the floating-rate bond is given by

Time $0$: Payment of \$$100$.

Time $1/2$: Receipt of \$($50r_{0,0.5}$).

$\vdots$

Time $T-1/2$: Receipt of \$($50r_{T-1,T-0.5}$).

Time $T$: Receipt of \$($100+50r_{T-0.5,T}$).

> I am interested in computing
>
> (i) the present value of the bond;
>
> (ii) the Macaulay's duration of the bond.

**First question**:

Seemingly, by some arguments of replicating portfolio, one can always show that any bond with this structure has present value equal to the par value (page 4 of the following link):

http://people.stern.nyu.edu/jcarpen0/courses/b403333/09floater.pdf

Therefore, it seems that by the same argument, the present value is \$$100$. Is this correct?

**Second question**:

I am totally lost. By the definition of Macaulay's duration, for any bond with **constant yield** $i$ and coupon payments $c_{t_1}, \ldots, c_{t_k}$ at times $t_1, \ldots, t_k$ respectively,  the Macaulay's duration is defined by
$$ D= \sum_{j=1}^k t_j \bigg[ \frac{ \frac{c_{t_j}}{(1+i)^{t_j}} }{B} \bigg], $$
where $B$ denotes the bond value. This clearly has no use in this problem as the coupon cash-flows are unknown. I notice that there are similar discussions on this theme, but the answer seems impossible to follow for me, e.g.

[Duration. Floating rate note](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/46580/duration-floating-rate-note)

Can anyone write down an explicit formula to compute the duration, as clear as possible, for a beginner like me? Thanks.

Comment: The *first* coupon payment is known, and this allows you to compute the duration (which will be small).

Comment: @AlexC Why? Can you please write down the explicit formula? Based on the definition, the coupons at all times have to be used to compute the duration.

Comment: Just set $k=1$ in your formula, i.e. take only the first coupon into account, the others have zero duration since they will be reset as interest rates change. You get $D=-\frac{1}{B}\frac{c_1/2}{(1+i/2)^{t_1}}$

Comment: @AlexC What do you mean by “reset”? Why are the other coupons zero?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to both your questions can already be found in [Duration. Floating rate note](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/46580/duration-floating-rate-note?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Duration of a floating rate bond](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/23278/duration-of-a-floating-rate-bond?rq=1), or the notes you linked to, but I'll write out the details for a non-replicating portfolio argument.

The value of a floating rate bond (floater) will always be equal to par assuming that the coupon reset is equal to the prevailing 6-month rate, $r_{n-0.5, n}$. To see this, start by considering $P(T-0.5)$, the price of the bond at $T - 0.5$. Since $P(T-0.5)$ is the present value (at time $T-0.5$) of the cash flows received at the maturity of the bond , we have:

$$
P(T-0.5) = \frac{100 + 100 \cdot \frac{r_{T-0.5,T}}{2}}{1 + \frac{r_{T-0.5,T}}{2}} = 100
$$

Similarly, $P(T-1)$ is equal to the present value of the sum of $P(T-0.5)$ and the coupon payment received at $T - 0.5$, $100 \cdot r_{T-1, T-0.5}/2$:

$$
P(T-1) = \frac{P(T-0.5) + 100 \cdot \frac{r_{T-1,T-0.5}}{2}}{1 + \frac{r_{T-1,T-0.5}}{2}} = 100
$$

By continuing to run this argument "backward", we conclude that $P(0)$, the present value of the floater, is 100.

The Macaulay Duration formula you cite above is generally only defined for a bond with fixed cash flows and does not apply here. Another way to proceed is to first calculate the modified duration $D_{Mod} = - \frac{1}{P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, where $y$ is the yield of the bond, and then use the relationship $D_{Mac} = D_{Mod}*(1+y/2)$ (assuming semi-annual compounding).

Now, our argument above shows that any time $t$ between 0 and 0.5, the price of the floater is given by:

$$
P(t,y) = \frac{100 + 100 \cdot \frac{r_{0,0.5}}{2}}{(1 + \frac{y}{2})^p}
$$
where $p$ is the fraction of the 6-month period corresponding to the interval $(t, 0.5)$.

Then:
$$
D_{Mod} = - \frac{1}{P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\frac{p}{2}}{1 + \frac{y}{2}}
$$

We conclude that $D_{Mac} = \frac{p}{2}$ and in particular that at $t=0$, $D_{Mac} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

On valuation this may be useful: http://www.fimmda.org/uploads/general/Rajwade16may.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question. The problem with your approach is that the coupon payment streams are unknown, since we do not know the values $r_{n-0.5,n}$....

Comment: Please see the link.

Comment: I saw this before, but don’t really think that this is helpful...